# How change text color in a column in TTNTListView?

Tags: delphi, tlistview

I use a TTNTListView in Delphi 7.
It is set to vsReport.
At OnCustomDrawSubItem event I use this code:

```
procedure TForm.ListViewCustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
   Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
   var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
   if SubItem = 2 then
      if (Item.SubItems.Strings[1] = Text1) or (Item.SubItems.Strings[1] = Text2) then
         Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clGreen
      else
         Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
end;
```

The problem is that all subitems >= 3 are drawn with the same color as subitem 2. I checked and for SubItem >= 3 Sender.Canvas.Font.Color is clBlack but they are drawn with clRed and clGreen.
If it's a problem in my code please show me how to fix it.
If it's a bug maybe someone knows a workaround.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you simply need to explicitly set the color for the other cases. Since you aren't doing so the canvas state persists. Try this:

```
procedure TForm.ListViewCustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
   Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
   var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  Color: TColor;
begin
  if SubItem = 2 then
    if (Item.SubItems.Strings[1] = Text1) or (Item.SubItems.Strings[1] = Text2) then
      Color := clGreen
    else
      Color := clRed;
  else
    Color := clBlack;
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := Color;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. Like I said I checked and for SubItems >= 3 is clBlack already so seting it to clBlack has no effect.

Comment: I don't have `TTNTListView` but it looks like an extension of the standard list view, `TListView`. With `TListView`, your code behaves as you described and my code behaved correctly, i.e. All columns blacks apart from column 3 (sub item 2). So if my code which works for me doesn't work for you then either 1. the TNT component differs in some important way or 2. you have more code that is confounding the issue. Try running with just a TNT list view using my code. Should be able to narrow it down easily enough.

Comment: Seems like is 1. I checked in a separate program: with TListView works fine, with TNTListview doesn't. Any ideas..?

Comment: Can you check again. It appears that the TNT control is derived from the standard Delphi control and the event you are handling is the Delphi event. If it really behaves differently then surely it's a bug. In which case, why not use the standard component?

Comment: Yes, it behaves differently. And I cannot use standard component because TNT = Unicode, in Delphi 7 the standard component is not Unicode. For this project I can't use a newer version of Delphi.

Comment: I tested in Delphi 2009 and it's the same problem with ListView. But I noticed something very strange. Your code works with TNTListView in Delphi 7 and with ListView in Delphi 2009 ONLY if in that event I use a color for Subitem <> 2 (last else which you added) different from ListView.Font.Color. For example if I use clblack for one and clWindowText for the other, it works. But if I use the same color (any) for both, it's not working. It's good that partially works, but I need to work with the same color (most probably I will use clWindowText).