# Simple TListView OwnerDraw Text Font Size and Color example?

Tags: delphi, ownerdrawn, tlistview

I am trying to owner draw a List View control in report-mode  with 4 columns, using `OnCustomDrawItem`.

When I try to change the Canvas.font.color, and that's all I do, I have no problems.

If I set canvas.font.size, I find that there is no change in the size of the text drawn by the control.

If I try to take over the painting of the text, from within OnCustomDrawItem, I find I can not.   I am aware of how to use OnCustomDraw to draw in the background area, but I want to custom draw a listview ITEM, so that I can set the color and font name and font size of the text.

I know that there are some problems with using Canvas in the context of ListView owner draw, and some limitations of what you can do in a ListView.

```
procedure TForm1.MyListViewCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Size := 13; // NO effect.
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed; // WORKS.
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Style  :=Sender.Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold]; // WORKS!
end;
```

Comment: Related but without font size changing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696499/how-change-text-color-in-a-column-in-ttntlistview

Comment: Are you wanting different font sizes and font faces for different items? That's what I can't work out how to do.

Comment: Apparently, you can change the font size, but of course, all the row heights have to be the same, so you can only change the font sizes within the range that will all fit in the existing row height.

Comment: @WarrenP No problem setting a too large font height here [see screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGTQ3.png).

Comment: I call clipping a problem, dunno about your standards. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue on TDBGrid.

Try to call  `Canvas.Refresh` after you reassign the Canvas.Font properties.

Comment: You misunderstood. Refresh is for the canvas, not the List. "TCanvas.Refresh". From the doc.: "Calling any of the drawing methods of the canvas after calling Refresh will reselect the Font, Brush, or Pen into the HDC"

Comment: DBGrid and List, yes are two different world. But Canvas is not. It's a HDC for both controls.

Comment: That worked, if I put it AFTER. Actually it IS pertinent. Thank you CHristopher. What an odd thing.

Comment: I think embarcadero changed the implemention of the setters of Canvas properties. On newer versions of Delphi one have to call canvas.refresh so internally the VCL update the HDC object. Maybe for better performance.

Comment: Until now, I didn't even know `TCanvas` had a `Refresh` method!

Comment: I do apologise. Now upvoted. This quite possibly is relevant to other issues I have experienced with list views. Thanks.

Comment: Undocumented breakage in the VCL.  What fun.