# Extending DBGrid with some row colors

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7

I want to extend DbGrid functionality to add colors on odd and even rows. So i wrote this

```
procedure TGridx.DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState);
var
  row : Integer;
begin
   inherited;
  row := Self.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo;
  if (row mod 2 = 0) then
    Self.Canvas.Brush.Color := FColor1  //some color
  else
    Self.Canvas.Brush.Color := FColor2; //some color

end;
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/a/grid_row_alt_cl.htm). you might want to use `inherited` before the event exits, or try calling `DefaultDrawColumnCell`.

Comment: i tried both i can't cal DefaultDrawColumnCell because i am overriding a method that doesn't have parameters for that function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event you want is called `DBGridDrawColumnCell`, and you need to decide whether to turn the DefaultDrawing property on or off, and the way you handle DBGridDrawColumnCell changes accordingly. For your case, you just set the colors, but leave DefaultDrawing true, and don't do any other canvas.Text or GDI drawing.

A recent question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537433/simple-tlistview-ownerdraw-text-font-size-and-color-example) showed that in later Delphi versions (2010,Xe,Xe2) you ALSO sometimes need to call `Canvas.Refresh` for both TDBGRID and TListView, when changing canvas properties in ownerdraw events but that doesn't apply to delphi 7.

Answer (score 1):

you should try also 3d party solution which are free, and extends already a lot the DBGrid, like the ones provided by the [Jedi project](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/)

Comment: does it have in line search too ? I mean if you press a key will it get to that letter ?

Answer (score 0):

Opc0de, may be you should override not the "DrawCell" method but "DrawCellBackground"?

Comment: DrawCellBackground not found in base class

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: I am sorry I can't help. I don't have Delphi 7. Obviously there are differences between 7 and XE :)

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing the cell as well after the brush color is defined:

```
Self.Canvas.FillRect(ARect);
```